# What is the correct way to add a Sliver Widget to a Non Sliver Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically I want to resolve this error.

```
RenderPadding expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverList.
```

Comment: You can use ListView.builder instead of `RenderSliverList` on this case.  a sample snippet may help

Answer (score 1):

You can not add Sliver widgets to a Non Sliver Widget unless to put your Non Sliver widget in a `SliverToBoxAdapter` to keep it using Sliver

```
       CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Widget1()
             ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Widget2()
             ),
          ],
        ),
```

read Sliver [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/slivers) carefully

and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54973948/8388842), it may help you.

happy coding.